# How do I use the ConsulDiscoveryClient with Zuul and Sidecar in Spring-Cloud

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, consul

I'm trying to use the Spring-Cloud microservice architecture with the Sidecar and Zuul components from Netflix following [an example from kbastani on github](https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example)

The environment where the services will be deployed already have a running consul service, which can be used for service discovery and configuration. This should mean that I can eliminate the config-service and eureka from the example.

I'm now trying to wire the api-gateway microservice to Consul with the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("consulDiscoveryClient")
    DiscoveryClient discovery;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gatewayApplication.MyZuulProxyConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration.discovery; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: consulDiscoveryClient,discoveryClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration.discovery; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: consulDiscoveryClient,discoveryClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: consulDiscoveryClient,discoveryClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 34 more
```

The pom.xml for this service is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api-gateway-microservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.quby.nxt</groupId>
        <artifactId>springCloudSpike</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: consul
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true

encrypt:
  failOnError: false
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 10000

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false
```

Can anyone shed a light on how I could use Spring cloud with Consul as a discovery and configuration service to create aan api-gateway?

Comment: Why do you want to use the sidecar with consul? The reason for existence of the sidecar is that eureka is JVM based. As consul is not, it in and of itself IS a sidecar.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction.
My mistake, I was under the impression that Sidecar was a necessary part of the API-Gateway. Actually Zuul is the one for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@EnalbeZuulProxy`, the sidecar is intended for non java services to serve as a service discovery client. `@EnalbeZuulProxy` will also enable discovery client for you.

Also your error is clearly stating that you are trying to autowire the `DiscoveryClient` by interface and there is already two of it in your context.The one spring-boot autoconfigures and the one you created.

You shouldn't create the client yourself, since the autoconfiguration will do it for you if the appropriate dependencies are on your classpath.

Sample working consul client:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/tree/master/spring-cloud-consul-sample

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Using `@EnableZuulProxy` and not trying to wire the DiscoveryClient myself has indeed done the job. Trying to wire it myself was a reaction on Spring Cloud not being able to choose itself.
I also removed the `@EnableSidecar` annotation and Sidecar as a dependency as suggested by @spencergibb above.